# How to join tables in a single query, when some queries return null or 0

Tags: sql-server

I have three different queries that return different COUNT values, according to some specific parameters in each query. When I run them separately they work fine, but I need them to return a single table. So, when any of those queries return a null value, it wont bring the same rows.

The first query goes like this:

```
SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre] AS [Medio]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
```

This will return this results:

```
|ID    |    Medio         |
---------------------------
|23    |    Prospectos    |
---------------------------
|29    |    Pop up        |
---------------------------
|1     |    Facebook      |
---------------------------
|24    |    Referidos     |
---------------------------
|30    |    Pto. info     |
---------------------------
|4     |    Google        |
---------------------------
|25    |    Directo       |
---------------------------
|5     |    Display       |
---------------------------
```

The second query will go like this:

```
SELECT
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
        COUNT(*) AS [regs]
    FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
        ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
    WHERE
        ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
    GROUP BY
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
```

And brings this results:

```
|ID    |    Medio         |
---------------------------
|23    |    1379          |
---------------------------
|29    |    8             |
---------------------------
|1     |    54            |
---------------------------
|24    |    2             |
---------------------------
|30    |    4             |
---------------------------
|4     |    325           |
---------------------------
|25    |    501           |
---------------------------
|5     |    6             |
---------------------------
```

The third query, similar to the second one, but with different parameters in a WHERE Clause, will bring the same information, but, when there is no results in one of the "Medio" options, it won't bring that specific row:

```
SELECT
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
        COUNT(*) AS [regs]
    FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
        ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
    WHERE
        ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
        AND
        (
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '3') 
            OR
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '4') 
            OR
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '8') 
            OR
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '19') 
            OR
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '20') 
            OR
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '21')
        ) 

    GROUP BY
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
        [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
```

Will return this:

```
|ID    |    Medio         |
---------------------------
|1     |    9             |
---------------------------
|4     |    35            |
---------------------------
|23    |    100           |
---------------------------
|24    |    2             |
---------------------------
|25    |    152           |
```

So when I join the three queries into a single one, it will ignore those rows, even though the first query has them!

```
SELECT
    [Medios].[Medio],
    [Preinscritos].[regs] AS [Preinscritos],
    [Admitidos].[regs] AS [Admitidos]
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre] AS [Medio]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Medios]
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                COUNT(*) AS [regs]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Preinscritos]
        ON [Medios].[ID] = [Preinscritos].[MedioId]
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
                COUNT(*) AS [regs]
            FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
                ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
            WHERE
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
                AND
                (
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '3') 
                    OR
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '4') 
                    OR
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '8') 
                    OR
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '19') 
                    OR
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '20') 
                    OR
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '21')
                ) 

            GROUP BY
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
                [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
        ) [Admitidos]
        ON [Medios].[ID] = [Admitidos].[MedioId]
```

This is the result from that query:

```
|Medio        |    Preinscritos    |   Admitidos  |
---------------------------------------------------
|Facebook     |    54              |   9          |
---------------------------------------------------
|Google       |    325             |   35         |
---------------------------------------------------
|Prospectos   |    1379            |   100        |
---------------------------------------------------
|Referidos    |    2               |   2          |
---------------------------------------------------
|Directo      |    501             |   152        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

So, as you can see, when I join the queries, the results on "pop up", "referidos" and "Pto. info" are beeing ignored, because they are NULL or 0 on the third query (which builds the results for the "Admitidos" column).

How can I achieve this consult???

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
SELECT
[Medios].[Medio],
[Preinscritos].[regs] AS [Preinscritos],
[Admitidos].[regs] AS [Admitidos]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre] AS [Medio]
        FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
            ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
        WHERE
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
        GROUP BY
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
    ) [Medios]
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
            COUNT(*) AS [regs]
        FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
            ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
        WHERE
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
        GROUP BY
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
    ) [Preinscritos]
    ON [Medios].[ID] = [Preinscritos].[MedioId]
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] AS [MedioId],
            COUNT(*) AS [regs]
        FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta]
            ON [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[MedioId] 
        WHERE
            ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @prd)
            AND
            (
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '3') 
                OR
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '4') 
                OR
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '8') 
                OR
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '19') 
                OR
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '20') 
                OR
                ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = '21')
            ) 

        GROUP BY
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[ID],
            [dbo].[Medios_Pauta].[Nombre]
    ) [Admitidos]
    ON [Medios].[ID] = [Admitidos].[MedioId]
```

Because that way if the join dynamic tables are null, it will show rows anyway.

Comment: Thanks! How can I replace the NULL values. I'm trying with ISNULL(COUNT(*), '') But it still gets me a NULL

Comment: Try `coalesce(count(*), 0)`, then it will replace null values to 0

Answer (score 2):

can you replace JOIN with Left join between  [Medios]  and [Preinscritos]  and [Admitidos]